# Upgrade OS on ZFS file server

Tags: centos7, zfs, upgrade, rocky-linux

I need to upgrade the OS of my ZFS disk server from CentOS 7 to Rocky Linux 9. I am currently running ZFS 2.0.7, and if I'm correct Rocky Linux 9 uses 2.3. My tentative plan is to use the AlmaLinux Elevate scripts to perform the migration to Rocky Linux 8 and then upgrade to Rocky Linux 9, as explained [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/migrate-centos-to-rocky-linux). The OS resides in a dedicate SSD.

Since the server size is quite big (24 x 16 TB disks in ZRAID2 configuration) I have no backup possibility. Data loss is not an option, so I'm worried about possible troubles, e.g.:

1. is there any chance that upgrading the OS would result in pool corruption / data loss?
2. should I expect issues due to the upgrade of the ZFS version?
3. is the linked upgrade procedure robust? Could it be more safe to simply do a fresh install of Rocky 9 and reconfigure everything?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Create a test lab in VMs and try.

Comment: Implement backup first. Not only for this case, if data loss is not an option running it without backups is a straight path to disaster.

Comment: I have no resources for a backup, and I must rely on RAID.

Comment: RAID is not a backup. It won't protect you from `rm -rf` or botched upgrade.

Comment: I know, but I need a lot of space and cannot afford more for backup. I know the risk I'm taking, I am obviously not comfortable with this but there's nothing I can do at the moment.

Comment: @NicolaMori, **RAID is not backup** moreover with such huge disks RAID6 probably is not enough. You must migrate to RAID Z3 **AND** hot spare disks (at least 2 for so many disks). AND implement backup

Comment: I'd not use a single array of that large even with RAIDZ3. OpenZFS manual [doesn't recommend it explicitly](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Performance%20and%20Tuning/Workload%20Tuning.html#pool-geometry-1) either: "Do not put more than ~16 disks in raidz." The way to do with such a large pool is to have two or three top-tier zvol's, RAIDZ2 or RAIDZ3 each. of 12 or 8 disks in each respectively. In "ordinary RAID" terminlogy this translates into "RAID60" (RAID0 out of several RAID6's).

Comment: Sorry, I've made a little mistake: my pool is actually made of a RAID0 of  two ZRAID2 with 12 disks each. And again, I cannot backup 250 TB of data, I barely have the plain storage size for that.

Answer (score 7):

If there is not much to configure, I'd perform a fresh install. But your plan looks sensible, and if there is much configuration (and it wasn't automated), the upgrade path is to go. I went it once (I was upgrading from Centos 7 to then-recent AlmaLinux, but that shouldn't matter), with success.

The backup is **mandatory**. You should **expect** you'll screw up a few times, so the ability to restart from scratch is a must. However, you don't need to backup the datastore; only the system. I believe you can afford backing up that, considering it's residing on the separate storage.

Physically detach the pool, backup the system, and then either reinstall or upgrade while pool is detached. Newer ZFS is able to import the older version pool, so once you determined you have everything to your liking, you'll attach the pool back and then [upgrade](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/8/zfs-upgrade.8.html) it (also look [here](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/man/master/8/zpool-upgrade.8.html)).

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. That's exactly the information I was looking for.

Comment: If you don't already have a backup process in place and working, then clearly the data isn't that important.

Comment: I like how everybody plays smart when it's not their problem to find a spare 250 TB to make backup. Of course, everybody has a few hundreds of terabytes in their pocket. Friends, just think: what if *this* is a backup? What do you expect to have, backup of backup? And then, backup of backup of backup? Reasonable practices should be *reasonable*, and **no definite dogma could ever be reasonable**, even "you should make a backup" one.

Comment: Thank you Nikita, I was growing tired of repeating myself...

Comment: As a follow up: the upgrade procedure with Elevate failed miserably. I hit his problem: https://github.com/rhboot/efibootmgr/issues/191, and I was not lucky enough to be left with a bootable system. So I wiped the OS disk, installed Rocky Linux 9 from scratch, reconfigured everything, and then re-imported the ZFS pool. Everything worked absolutely beautifully, especially the recovery of the ZFS, so I suggest to avoid Elevate and go with an installation from scratch if/when feasible.